# Is there a way I can order the columns of a table but show specific rows in a determined position?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables: t1, which shows the countries, and t2, which shows people.

```
T1:                                   T2:
ID | Country  | Continent             ID | Name     | Age  | CountryID           
--------------------------            ---------------------------------
1  | England  | Europe                1  | Mary     | 67   |     1
2  | USA      | NA                    2  | Anthoine | 34   |     2
3  | Portugal | Europe                3  | Jorge    | 19   |     3
4  | Canada   | NA                    4  | Bella    | 46   |     4
                                      5  | Ana      | 26   |     2
```

My goal is to display the number of people living in each country and continent and group them by continent and country, as shown below:

```
Continent | Country  | Bellow 45 yo | Above 45 yo | Total Habitants
-------------------------------------------------------------------
Europe    | Europe   |      1       |      1      |       2 
Europe    | England  |      0       |      1      |       1 
Europe    | Portugal |      1       |      0      |       1 
NA        | NA       |      2       |      1      |       3 
NA        | Canada   |      0       |      1      |       1 
NA        | USA      |      2       |      0      |       2
```

But this is what I'm getting:

```
Continent | Country  | Bellow 45 yo | Above 45 yo | Total Habitants
-------------------------------------------------------------------
Europe    | England  |      0       |      1      |       1 
Europe    | Europe   |      1       |      1      |       2 
Europe    | Portugal |      1       |      0      |       1 
NA        | Canada   |      0       |      1      |       1
NA        | NA       |      2       |      1      |       3 
NA        | USA      |      2       |      0      |       2
```

This is my code:

```
SELECT t1.continent as Continent, t1.continent as Country
, COUNT(CASE WHEN t2.age < 45 THEN 1 END) AS Bellow 45 yo
, COUNT(CASE WHEN t2.age > 45 THEN 1 END) AS Above 45 yo
, COUNT(CASE WHEN t2.age > 45 or t2.age > 45 THEN 1 END) AS Total Habitants
FROM t1
JOIN t2 ON t2.id = t1.id
GROUP BY t1.continent
UNION
SELECT t1.continent as Continent, t1.country as Country
, COUNT(CASE WHEN t2.age < 45 THEN 1 END) AS Bellow 45 yo
, COUNT(CASE WHEN t2.age > 45 THEN 1 END) AS Above 45 yo
, COUNT(CASE WHEN t2.age > 45 or t2.age > 45 THEN 1 END) AS Total Habitants
FROM t1
JOIN t2 ON t2.id = t1.id
GROUP BY t1.continent,t1.country
```

I've tried `ORDER BY` but got an error:

> [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Incorrect syntax
> near the keyword 'UNION'.

Comment: Edit your question and show sample data.  What does the source data look like?

Comment: SELECT * FROM (Your code that you wrote here) as R  order by columnName1,columnName2

Comment: @GordonLinoff Simplified the question and added the sample data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, simplify the query using `GROUPING SETS`.  Then you can easily add an `ORDER BY` to get the ordering you want:

```
SELECT t1.continent as Continent,
       COALESCE(t1.country, t1.continent) as Country,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN t2.age < 45 THEN 1 END) AS under_45,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN t2.age > 45 THEN 1 END) AS over_45,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN t2.age > 45 or t2.age > 45 THEN 1 END) AS Total
FROM t1 JOIN
     t2
     ON t2.id = t1.id
GROUP BY GROUPING SETS ( (t1.continent, t1.country), (t1.continent) )
ORDER BY t1.continent,
         (CASE WHEN t1.country IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 2 END),
         t1.country;
```

Comment: I don't think coalesce applies to me because there aren't any null countries. Maybe I'm looking at coalesce wrong and if I am please clarify me.

Comment: @pauLo_0liveira . . . The `NULL` values are created by the `grouping sets`.  You can also use `case` with the `grouping()` function, but `coalesce()` is usually simpler and works.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm reading through the lines correctly, are you not after this?

```sql
ORDER BY continent,
         CASE continent WHEN country THEN 0 ELSE 1 END,
         country;
```

Comment: It looks like I can't use order, because every time I add the order clause I get this error :[Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'UNION'.

Comment: The `ORDER BY` needs to go at the end, @pauLo_0liveira, you can't use an `ORDER BY` and the `UNION` to another query. You're likely better off betting the `UNION`'d queries in a subquery and then the `ORDER BY` on the outside.

Comment: How can I do that? The first select, before UNION returns only the total habitants per continent, in this case Europe and NA, where can I add the code to show the countries under their respective continent?